# Google place search box is not working only in my html page

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

plz help, google place search box is not working in my html page. I tried even in a new page and still no result. It just showing like

[image]

when I type any place.Below are the code I used.

```html
<div id="locationField">
    <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text" />
  </div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCKQX3cyZ7pVKmBwE8wiowivW9qH62AVk8&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
  
  <script>var placeSearch, autocomplete, geocoder;

function initAutocomplete() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      (document.getElementById('autocomplete'))/*,
      {types: ['(cities)']}*/);

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function codeAddress(address) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        alert(results[0].geometry.location);
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

function fillInAddress() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  alert(place.place_id);
  //   codeAddress(document.getElementById('autocomplete').value);
}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow Sai!

When I copy and paste your example code to a new html file and open it with Chrome I get the same error as you. But there is a hint in the developer console what's wrong:

> Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
>
> Your site URL to be authorized: **file_url**/.../test.html

When you follow the link above you will get this explanation:

> RefererNotAllowedMapError
>
> The current URL loading the Maps JavaScript API has not been added to the list of allowed referrers. Please check the referrer settings of your API key on the Google Cloud Platform Console.

So you have to whitelist your pages URL for this feature. Hope this helps!